# How can I make my Ruby script announce values as it runs?

Tags: ruby, text-to-speech

Say I have captured two values, `1000` and `09/01/2016` (and let's pretend that today is `10/01/2016`).

How can I make Ruby convert the string `"one thousand for 30 days"` to audible speech within the console as it runs?

Comment: Ran `sudo gem install espeak-ruby` and placed `requre espeak-ruby` in script, but got following error: `require': cannot load such file -- espeak-ruby (LoadError)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the gem [humanize](https://github.com/radar/humanize) to convert the int 1000 to its name in english,

and you'd also nee something like `date1 - date2` to get the difference in days.

Something like:

```
number.humanize + ' for ' + (Date.today - myDate).to_i.to_s
```

In order to make the bash speak this string out loud, you could use the very say command you mentioned; ruby allows for easily calling bash commands from within the language, just do something like this:

```
str = number.humanize + ' for ' + (Date.today - myDate).to_i.to_s
`say #{str}`
```

Otherwise, if you want a more native solution, you can use the [espeak](https://github.com/dejan/espeak-ruby) gem:

```
speech = Speech.new(str)
speech.speak # invokes espeak
```

Comment: But then how to make it audible while it runs? Like OS X's `say 'hello'` functionality in terminal.

Comment: @Forwarding You can use `puts` or `p` to print values to stdout; e.g., `puts number.humanize + ' for ' + (Date.today - myDate)` . This will echo the resulting string in the terminal.

Comment: Yes, but I'm talking like audible speech as it runs.

Comment: @Forwarding oh, so that's what the `say` command does... I though it just print to the screen. Then you can call this very command from ruby using backticks, like `\`say #{str}\``.

Comment: @Forwarding no, humanize does not speak, just converts int to string.

Comment: Hmm... Is there anyway I can then have a live microphone linked to the program in realtime so that when I hear a value I don't want I can just yell, "NO" and it won't store that value? I just want this thing to be running, and then I can go make bacon or something while it runs and I can say YES or NO depending on what I hear.

Comment: Or like a remote control yes/no button.

Comment: @Forwarding `humanize` converts `2` to `"two"`. And similarly for other numbers.

Comment: So it has to be an number?

Comment: @Forwarding yes. See this [link](https://github.com/radar/humanize) for more examples.

Comment: @Forwarding that's a bit more complicated to achieve, but it is certainly possible. Take a look at this gem: https://github.com/nanki/ffi-portaudio